# dyld: Symbol not found

Tags: node.js

I have installed npm `n` to try and load version 0.10 of node to try react-native.

The error I receive is

`dyld: Symbol not found: 
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation`

Is there an easy way to make this work? I can then use the latest version of node if I use `n 0.12.1` and node works again in the terminal, but wont run the older version that react is wanting.